# How to check if Doctrine entity is persisted and flushed to database?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit

I want to write a test case which verifies that an entity has been fully persisted to the database, via the Doctrine entity manager.

For example:

```
<?php

function notPersisted() {
    return new Entity();
}

function persistedButNotFlushed() {
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entityManager->persist($entity);

    return $entity;
}

function persistedAndFlushed() {
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entityManager->persist($entity);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $entity;
}

function persistedButNotAllChangesFlushed() {
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entityManager->persist($entity);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $entity->setFoo('bar');
    $entityManager->persist($entity);

    return $entity;
}

$this->assertNotPersistedToDb(notPersisted());
$this->assertNotPersistedToDb(persistedButNotFlushed());
$this->assertPersistedToDb(persistedAndFlushed());
$this->assertNotPersistedToDb(persistedButNotAllChangesFlushed());
```

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: `$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions()` seems like a good fit, doesn't it? Seeing as you're actually trying to assert what the `UnitOfWork` will be... [See what else you can do](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html)

Comment: Looks like you are testing D2 functionality.  Might want to rethink if these tests really accomplish anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with:

```
protected function assertEntityIsPersistedToDb($entity) {
    $unitOfWork = $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
    $isManaged = $this->entityManager->contains($entity);
    $isFlushedToDb = !$unitOfWork->isEntityScheduled($entity);

    $id = $this->getEntityId($entity);

    $entityClassName = get_class($entity);
    $msg = "Expected entity of type $entityClassName to be persisted to the database, ";

    if (!$id) {
        $msg .= "but the entity does not have an id.";
    }
    else if (!$isManaged) {
        $msg .= "but entity is not managed by the entity manager.";
    }
    else if (!$isFlushedToDb) {
        $msg .= "but the entity has changes which have not yet been flushed.";
    }

    $this->assertTrue(!!$id && $isManaged && $isFlushedToDb, $msg);
}

protected function assertEntityNotPersistedToDb($entity) {
    // Ensure that this is a managed entity
    if (!$this->entityManager->contains($entity)) {
        throw new \PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException(
            "Unable to determine if entity is persisted to DB: the entity is not managed."
        );
        // Alternatively, we could maybe do an $em->merge($entity),
        // and then check its state. However, this could change our application
        // state, and potential effect test behavior.
    }

    $isFlushedToDb = !$this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()
        ->isEntityScheduled($entity);

    $entityClass = get_class($entity);
    $msg = "Expected entity of type $entityClass not to be persisted to the database.";

    $this->assertFalse($isFlushedToDb, $msg);
}


protected function getEntityId($entity) {
    $idList = $this->entityManager
        ->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity))
        ->getIdentifier();

    return empty($idList) ?
        null : call_user_func([$entity, 'get' . ucfirst(reset($idList))]);
}
```

I've played around with it a bit and it seems to work, though I haven't put it through any kind of rigorous testing.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your work, detaching can be a pain when you have multiple associations within your objects and your cascade option was not set properly, these 2 functions help you assert or not the entity is managed within your application state.

```
static function assertEntityIsManaged(EntityManager $em, $entity) {
    $isManaged = $em->contains($entity);
    $entityClass = get_class($entity);
    $msg = "Expected entity of type $entityClass IS NOT Managed";
    assert($isManaged === TRUE, $msg);
}

static function assertEntityNotManaged(EntityManager $em, $entity) {
    $isManaged = $em->contains($entity);
    $entityClass = get_class($entity);
    $msg = "Expected entity of type $entityClass IS Managed";
    assert($isManaged === FALSE, $msg);
}
```

Static because its not a "formal" test, and I have multiple instances of entity managers.